# JavaScript: Storing dates in array in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, momentjs

I'm trying to loop through to check if the first date is less than the second date. If it is, I want to store the value in an array, add 1 day to the first date, then go back through the process. I think that's what I've written, but I'm not sure why it's not working. When I console out any any of the array values, it's always the last date that appears and I can't get any of the other values to store. After stepping through it with Firebug, it looks like they are being overwritten. I'm using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to get the dates.

```
var counter = 1;
var arr = [];
var i = firstDate.toDate();

for(counter; firstDate < secondDate; counter++){
        arr[i]=firstDate.toDate();
        firstDate.add(1, "day");
    }

console.log(arr[2]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `i` never changes once set, so you're constantly writing to the same index.

Also, your `counter` variable is never used. Consider using your `counter` variable as the index as it will be unique for each iteration. Alternatively, if you want to continue using the date as an index, add the line `i = firstDate.toDate();` to the top of your for loop.

For the latter, your loop should look like this:

```
var counter = 1;
var arr = [];
var i = firstDate.toDate();

for(counter; firstDate < secondDate; counter++){
    i = firstDate.toDate();
    arr[i]=firstDate.toDate();
    console.log(firstDate.toDate());
    firstDate.add(1, "day");
}
console.log(arr[2]);
```

I suggest adding a console log to your loop (as above) if you're having problems, to see which dates are being added as they are being added.

Comment: So I tried moving `i = firstDate.toDate()` into my loop, but I still get the same outcome. Is there something else I need to adjust as well?

Comment: See my edit, using that for loop, what gets printed to the console?

Comment: The `console.log(firstDate.toDate());` inside the for loop consoles out each day of the month, but the `console.log(arr[2]);` consoles out undefined

Answer (score 0):

Since the difference between first and second date is unknown beforehand you could use a while loop instead

```
while( firstDate.isBefore(secondDate) ) {
    arr.push(firstDate.toDate());
    firstDate.add(1, 'day');
}
```